# Copy column values to another column in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, copy

I'm trying to copy  title column to keywords column in database, so the keywords will be inserted automatically from the title.

http://store2.up-00.com/2015-06/1435609110941.png

I want to add  comma ', ' before each word for example.

```
" It's my first program "
```

it will turn into

```
" It's, my, first, program, "
```

This the code I wrote.

```
<?php

  // $id =mysql_insert_id;
  $select_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts`");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_posts)){
        $id  = $row['post_id'];
        $text =  $row['post_title'];  

       $delim = ' \n\t,.!?:;';
       $tok = strtok($text, $delim);


    while ( $tok !== false){
          echo $tok1 = $tok.',';
          mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET  `post_keywords` =  '$tok1' WHERE `post_id` = $id  ");
          $tok = strtok($delim);
        }   
}

?>
```

it insert the last word in each title column , because the words is overwritten  by while loop.

Please help me .

Comment: I think you need to move your update query out of the inner while loop and use concatenation for the `$tok1` variable.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if you need this: `$tok = strtok($delim);` inside the inner while loop.

Comment: I tried to move them before but it didn't work  Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a single query :

```
UPDATE `posts` SET post_keywords = REPLACE(post_title, ' ', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Concat the values:

```
... SET post_keywords = CONCAT(post_keywords, '$tok1')
```

and note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Just because that $tok1 value came out of a database doesn't mean it's safe to REUSE in a query...

Comment: it's a test file to insure that the code works , Will use tmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string () ) inside the function later.

Comment: wrong. escaping for sql is the **LAST** thing you do. if you mangle the string after escape, you risk UNDOING the escaping.  you should NOT be using mysql_*() functions anymore. switch to PDO and placeholders, and then you don't have to worry about escaping at all anymore.

Comment: you code worked but it inserted all the columns values together.

Comment: well, what else do you expect? you're using `post_keywords` in your query, so I used that here too. if each $tok1 belongs in a separate column, then your sample code is useless...